# summary row for a grid in dojo

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I Am looking for  a Summary row or a Footer row for a grid where i can display total value of all column ,This footer row should not get scrolled(Virtically) .

Please Correct me if i am wrong .A Summary row  for a Grid is not available in Dojo as a Default widget.

I Have achieved the above Summary row feature for Grid By

1) Adding a second grid only with Header Just below the Grid where you want footer row ,as a whole its look like a footer row to a Grid

Problems faced are

1) Column resizing i.e., when you resize any column in Grid 1 the same column in Grid 2(Grid with only Header ) must be resized

The above problem can be solved be capturing a resizing event in Grid 1 and propagating the event to Grid 2.

2) When you resize the column we will get Horizontal scroll Bar For both the Grids

Is there a way to propagate Horizontal scroll event from Grid 1 to Grid 2 so that when u scroll the Grid 1 then simultaneously Grid  2 has to get scrolled  or how to get only one scroll for two Grids

Is there any other way to achive above feature for a grid .

Comment: Unfortunately, even with three grids (enhancedGrid, dgrid and gridx) it still doesn't look like Dojo supports a footer out of the box on a grid...

Comment: @ mtyson - yes you are correct Dojo dose not have any grid widget with the footer But what i have mentioned above is working for me as i have handled column resizing and hiding the horizontal scroll bar for first grid  ..So for there is no issue ...

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this by "stacking" the grids together.  A primary data and footer grid.  Use CSS to hide the heading of the footer grid.  You have to use javascript to update the sums for the footer grid.

Comment: @ Dennis I agree that is the solution but along with that you need to handle column resizing  because as u resize any of your column in primary data grid corresponding footer grid column should also resize..and also if u have more columns then you need to handel horizontal scroll bar also because as there are two grids if u scroll the foter grid scroll the corresponding primary data  grid content has to move ....I have achived these two(column resizing and horizontal scroll bar) and it working fine for me !!!!

Answer (score 0):

See [demo](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/summary_row/demo/SummaryRow.html) and [detailed reference](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/summary_row/)

> DoJo EnhancedGrid has a summary property that can be set, as described in the [api documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dojox_grid_EnhancedGrid_summary)